# Atomic transaction to update pair of related objects at once

Tags: django

I have a simple task - mark all User's and its Profiles as "is_active", and I do it like this:

```
users = User.objects.all().select_related('profile')

for user in users:
    user.is_active = True
    user.profile.is_active = True
    user.save()
    user_profile.save()
```

Sometimes it corrupts data, so user's is_active and user.profile's is_active not always synced

And the best plan I can think of is to wrap both .save()s into atomic transaction

```
from django.db import transaction

users = User.objects.all().select_related('profile')

for user in users:
    user.is_active = True
    user.profile.is_active = True
    with transaction.atomic():
        user.save()
        user_profile.save()
```

So, should it work?) The concern is - maybe whole block, including `users = User.objects.all().select_related('profile')` should be wrapped in transaction.atomic()

P.S. I can not use .update() due to complex logic inside

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.
But you can use a single save method call to perform an atomic transaction.

- for example like this:

```
user.save(update_fields=('is_active', 'profile__is_active'))
```

If you would like to understand this problem better, please have a look at the Django source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L763